# C# handle multiple events to main UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, event-handling, eventhandler

I have a group of objects that get updated periodically in its own thread ( Background worker ). My main form subscribes to a ValueChanged event from all those objects and updates some UI elements accordingly.

```
//pseudo code, this loops run on a timer  
foreach (obj myObj in myObjctList )
{
      myObj.Refresh()///// This raises an event if data changed 
}
```

Does this thread block if myObj raises and event and have to wait until the Main UI subscriber is finished before it continues with the next iteration of Refresh()?

If so, would raising the event with a Task / Thread better so it doesn't block the update thread? Not sure how would that work / how much overhead would be since it would continuously spawn new Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Put your code which is update your UI on between this...

```
public delegate void Action(); // declare as global
      this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {           
        // Your UI Updated code  
        }));
```